# How To get the Check Rule Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I get the **expression of a check constraint**?

With MSSMS I can easly see that Table `Person` has a `CHECK constraint` named `CK_Person` validating the expression `([DateOfBirth]<[DateOfDeath])`.

With this query I can get the `COLUMN_NAME`, `CONSTRAINT_NAME` and `CONSTRAINT_TYPE`:

```
SELECT CCU.COLUMN_NAME, CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME,  TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS CCU ON TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    WHERE TC.TABLE_NAME = 'Person'
```

Resulting

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| COLUMN_NAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME | CONSTRAINT_TYPE |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| PersonID    | PK_Person       | PRIMARY KEY     |
| DateOfBirth | CK_Person       | CHECK           |
| DateOfDeath | CK_Person       | CHECK           |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

But how can I get the actual expression itself?

Comment: Did you try executing sp_help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT definition AS Check_Expression
      ,name       AS ConstraintName
FROM sys.check_constraints
WHERE Parent_object_ID = OBJECT_ID('TableName')
```

Comment: I'm ashamed! It was so easy.
Thanks